# How to watch param of emitted function

Tags: vue.js, watch

I’m emitting a function from child to parent, like this

```
getCustomAddress (value) {
      const place = {
        name: value.formatted_address,
        lat: parseFloat(value.geometry.location.lat()),
        lon: parseFloat(value.geometry.location.lng())
      }
      this.$emit('getCustomAddress', place)
}
```

This value changes every time the user changes the address.
The child is a vue2 google maps autocomplete. I use it in the parent like this
`<auto @getCustomAddress="getCustomAddress" />`, but this function in the parent is called only once (the child is correctly detecting the value change).
I was wondering how I can watch this function param so that the parent always gets the last place chosen by the user.

Here is the getCustomAddress function in the parent

```
async getCustomAddress (place) {
        this.stopStart = place.name
        this.fullStops.push({
          name: place.name,
          custom: true,
          lat: place.lat,
          lon: place.lon
        })
        console.log('recall set custom')
        await this.setCustomStart({
          lat: place.lat,
          lng: place.lon
        })
      }
```

I am getting `this.setCustomStart` with mapActions.
Hope I’ve been clear enough.
Thank you.

Comment: Events are meant to be emitted instead of functions https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html
However, you can assign your results in a data and then you can watch that data.
Finally whenever an emit is thrown you already are notified for update, attempt to rewrite your approach and follow framework patterns, developing Anti-Pattern solutions can make you waste time and produce inefficient solutions.

Comment: Thanks @mentorgashi.I see. I thought that probably the problem was in my approach, but couldn't find another way to pass that place value from child to parent, so far. How would you suggest me to do it? Which pattern is the correct one?

Comment: Whenever the logic start overcoming the component and goes beyond Solid Principles in data composition please begin to use State Management using vuex, you can start learning how to use it in vuemastery.com or more basic approach with pure js as Jeffrey explains: https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step

Comment: I am using vuex, my problem is that getCustomAddress gets called only once, so I can call the action to set it in the store only once. I updated the question.

Comment: Okay there's a way to bind events and forward the emits to parent https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components <comp v-on="$listeners"></comp> see if that helps.

Comment: Yes, I read about it but didn't get how to use it. Sorry, could you tell me? I add  ```v-on="$listeners"``` to the child component in the parent, and that's it? In this way, if it works, it should detect the change of the param place?

Comment: Let's say you have 3 depth components like, C1, C2 and C3, and you want to access event of C3 in C1 by listening event in C2. 
Eg. you declare C2 in C1 `<c2 @getCustomAddress="getCustomAddress">` and in C3 you can just `<auto v-on="$listeners"></auto>`. So C3 will re-emit anything emitted by auto therefore C2 will be able to listen to any emit in auto. That should work and you can do this in any depth of components like C1 => <c2 v-on="$listeners">; C2 => <c3 v-on="$listeners">;  C3 => <auto v-on="$listeners">